# event does not work after append using document .on change

Tags: jquery

I am unable to get the alert to fire unsure what I am doing wrong.
I am attempting to bind events after the append
but for some reason I am unable to see the message from the alert box firing.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>mytitle</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('body').append('<div id="testdiv2"></div>');

            $('document').on("change", '#testdiv2', function () {
                alert("hello");
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for the responses.
what I am attempting to do is reference a div after I have created it for example.
say I want to append a div and then load content into it. then when that is complete remove all the labels from it. so something like this.

$(document).ready(function () {

```
        $('body').append('<div id="testdiv2"></div>').load('HtmlPage2.html #testdiv');

        $('testdiv2 label').remove()
    });
</script>
```

how would I accomplish something like that?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle on what you are  trying to ask?

Answer (score 2):

The [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event is triggered only by input elements having their value changed. The `<div>` itself can do nothing to trigger it.

Reference:

> The `change` event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>`
>   elements.

Answer (score 0):

Its `document` not `'document'`

```
        $(document).on("change", '#testdiv2', function () {
            alert("hello");
        });
```

`$('document')` attempts to find `<document>` tags in your document.

also `div` s have no change event

and you don't need to put a `$(document).on` inside a `$(document).ready` since the document is already available.